# Adding Image to XCode .m File for iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I would like to add an image (joke.png) to my XCode project. It should feature the GCRectMake settings of 0,190,320,60. How would I add it to the .m file code? Let's assume I already added it to the .h file under the UIButton list. It is just for display - no interaction. Thanks!

Comment: You should try and invest more time in writing your questions and then follow up with answers that users submit. It's unlikely that you will get quality answers with such a low accept rating.

Comment: Sorry for asking a question that "makes not sens." Typically, questions arise from not fully understanding something. Thanks for the help, Dan. That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to add an UIImageView to your view.

In your viewdidload create that imageview and add it to the view.

e.g

```
 UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[Uiiimage: imagenamed:@"joke.png"];
imageView.frame = cgrectmake( 0,190,320,60);
[self.view addSubview:image view];
```

Comment: This was assuming you really wanted a imageview not a button.